# Documents supporting a visa application

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

What if I just opened my bank account this month, and I'm planning to travel to the UK in December and visit my family for six months? Is it possible to get a  visa if I present that bank statement  which was open just recently?

Since this will be my last year in school, and I'm not employed, I am just a working part-time working at my Dad's workplace, and I receive my pay on a daily basis since I'm a casual worker without a payslip. Is there any other supporting document apart from my employer or school to offer for my UK visa application as supporting documents?

Comment: What is your nationality? Do you have any previous travel history? You will typically need to demonstrate a strong reason(s) that would compel you to return home plus good financial standing that is in line with your personal circumstances in your home country. This answer is extremely thorough and well worth reading to understand the pitfalls before you apply https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: UK immigration are looking for three things: you can support yourself during your visit; you won't work illegally; you will leave at the end of your visit. You're going to find it very difficult to satisfy the first part since support from your family is of only peripheral importance. As a single individual with only casual employment and family ties in the UK you'll find it difficult to satisy the last part. You're proposing to stay six months - demonstrating that you can do that without working will, I'd guess, be almost impossible. You're unlikely to get a visa on this basis.